# twisted client call from a library function

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.client

I'm trying to implement a function that will act as a Twisted client. It's called from code I don't have control over. I tried something like (this taken from the pbsimpleclient.py example code):

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import util

def remcall(**kw):
    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, factory)
    d = factory.getRootObject()
    # kw here is what's passed in via remcall
    d.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("echo", kw))
    d.addCallback(lambda echo: 'server echoed: '+repr(echo))
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(util.println)
    d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```

And the caller would make a call like:

```
remcall(hello=1, world=2)
remcall(hi=3, there=4)
```

But as you may have guessed, it gives a "twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable" error.

What's the best way to do this? I'm not so worried about getting a response from the remote end, but I should know if it's failing and why.

Comment: You don't start/stop, the reactor in the function. You start it at the end of your main function and stop it when you want to exit the program. Once.

Comment: But is there any way to have it running (maybe in a thread) and let the main thread return to the caller? Or is this something that can't be done with Twisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use crochet.

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

## Add these two lines
from crochet import setup, wait_for
setup()

from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import util

## Add a wait_for decorator
@wait_for(timeout=5.0)
def remcall(**kw):
    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, factory)
    d = factory.getRootObject()
    # kw here is what's passed in via remcall
    d.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("echo", kw))
    d.addCallback(lambda echo: 'server echoed: '+repr(echo))
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(util.println)
## Get rid of the reactor calls, and return d
#    d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
#    reactor.run()
    return d
```

Then the caller just calls

```
remcall(hello=1, world=2)
remcall(hi=3, there=4)
```

and crochet's @wait_for handles running remcall inside the reactor thread.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `reactor.run()` from the `remcall` function and append it at the end.  Also remove `d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())`

```
def remcall(**kw):
    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, factory)
    d = factory.getRootObject()
    # kw here is what's passed in via remcall
    d.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("echo", kw))
    d.addCallback(lambda echo: 'server echoed: '+repr(echo))
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(util.println)


remcall(hello=1, world=2)
remcall(hi=3, there=3)
reactor.run()    # this should be the last thing to run
```

The reactor can only be run once.  `reactor.stop()` function is being executed and it should not unless your application needs to stop running completely.  This is why you get the `ReactorNotRestartable` exception.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Other code I don't have control over will call remcall many times, and each time, a connection must be made to the remote side.

Comment: The answer shows multiple calls to remcall, just as it seems you would like.  Don't be misled by the fact that both calls happen before the reactor.run() call in this example.  They would work just as well if they were made after reactor.run().  However, what you can't do is "reactor.run(); remcall(...)" because reactor.run() does not return until the reactor stops.  Instead, you need another thread to do something like "reactor.callFromThread(lambda: remcall(...))" or to put the remcall(...) into a Twisted event handler.

Comment: So @mlv are you saying the code you don't have control over will import ``remcall`` and execute it?  Is the other code written using Twisted?  If it's not you'll have to run the reactor and function in a thread and the easiest way to do that is using ``crochet`` https://github.com/itamarst/crochet/.  Sorry for the misunderstanding, hopefully I got it now -__-

Comment: Yes, @notorious, crochet is exactly what I needed. Thanks!